# ¿Cómo hacer un COUNT de elementos con un GROUP BY por día, aunque no haya elementos en algunos días?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta SQL que me dice cuantos personas se han connectados al menos una vez el dia pasado (que pueden ver con un estracto de la base de datos en [este Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f19c58/2/0)):

```
SELECT `sessions`.`session_time` AS `session_time`, count(*) AS `count`
FROM `sessions`
GROUP BY `sessions`.`session_time`
ORDER BY `sessions`.`session_time` ASC
```

Me gustaria hacer una consulta para saber cuantos personas se han conectados al menos una vez durante el ano pasado.

Por ejemplo con este schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions
    (`App Type` varchar(11), `Lang` varchar(2), `Session ID` int, `session_time` datetime, `User ID` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO sessions
    (`App Type`, `Lang`, `Session ID`, `session_time`, `User ID`)
VALUES
    #july 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1193745),
    # june 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 12345),
    # june 2020
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 54321)

;
```

El 29 de junio 2021 debemos obtener Count = 7 (los seis pero obtenemos 6, mas 54321 que se conectaba en junio 2020).

Comment: La consulta que pones en la pregunta es la respuesta a tu pregunta, esa consulta no tiene ningún filtro, por lo que te va a traer todas las conexiones de todos los tiempos.

Comment: Sin embargo @Marc , si tomo a todos los que se han conectado al menos una vez en el último año, debería tener 7 para junio 29 de 2021 y obtengo 6.

Comment: Yo veo 6 registros en Junio de 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de revisar tu pregunta he entendido que es lo que buscas, aunque no queda muy claro tal y como está planteado.

El objetivo es sacar las personas que se han conectado en un rango de X fechas, cosa que eso está puesto en la pregunta, pero en la query que nos muestras no es así, ya que no hay filtro.

Para conseguir lo que comentas deberías añadir filtros a la query indicando que el campo `sessions.session_time` debería estar dentro de un rango específico de fechas, lo haríamos de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`USER ID`))
FROM sessions
WHERE sessions.session_time BETWEEN '2020-06-29' AND '2021-06-29'
```

Nos interesa buscar los usuarios diferentes en ese rango de fechas, por eso, para obtener el contador de los id de usuarios diferentes usamos:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(`USER ID`))
```

Puedes ver el resultado en [este enlace](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f19c58/22/0).

EDIT:

Para obtener el contador de registros de usuarios diferentes un año atrás para cada dia informado en la tabla debes hacerlo con una subconsulta de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT sessions.session_time, (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`USER ID`)) 
  FROM sessions s2 
  WHERE s2.session_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(sessions.session_time, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND sessions.session_time
)
FROM sessions
GROUP BY sessions.session_time
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f19c58/37).

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Marc ! Sin embargo, ¿cómo hacer que esta mirada un año en el pasado para cada día ?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica Te he editado la respuesta añadiendo lo que buscas.

Comment: A mí me parece bien, el problema que tengo es que no produce ninguna salida después de 5 minutos. Creo que tendré que hacer otra cosa... Tendré que crear una tabla en mi ETL que lo calcule cada día... ¿O utilizar PySpark?